# Primefaces 6 dialog: resizable does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My code:

```
<h:body class="login-body">
    <p:dialog widgetVar="mainAddDialog" resizable="true" header="TEST"
         modal="true">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="TEST CMD"></p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('mainAddDialog').show();"></p:commandButton>
```

and the Dialog can not resize!
Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: So it worked in previous versions? And does it work in later versions? And it does work if you remove the height/width auto? Please investigate more...

Comment: Remove height/width, but it still does not work. The previous version I have not tested.

Comment: That is what you imply by adding a version to a title... Otherwise just add version info in the question. And **always** try newer versions....

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank, but my project is based on PF 6.

Comment: Just create a new empty project purely for testing this specific case. This way you can easily check if your problem is not already fixed in a newer PF version.

Comment: TRY, in a very small [mcve]. If it works, upgrade or create a patch. I'm not going to spend time investigating something that might already work in newer versions.

Comment: @BalusC thanks bro. It still does not work!

Comment: @Kukeltje PF version 6.2 is still does not work @@

Comment: There is still a height and width in you question. And what about the modal? Tried removing that? Why not? And the class/css on everything? resizing a modal works btw in the showcase in  PF 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened and in my project. I use [the Manhattan theme](https://www.primefaces.org/layouts/manhattan) and Primefaces 7
The problem I think is the css from the theme.

```
 body .ui-dialog .ui-resizable-handle {
display: none !important; }
```

If I override these rule it works fine.

```
    body .ui-dialog .ui-resizable-handle {
            display: block !important;
             }
```